# Ansible and shared components

Tags: ansible, microservices

I have multiple services which communicate with each other through rabbitmq. Each service has a repository and an ansible script for deployment. But I do not know where a good place for the rabbitmq ansible scripts.

I think about:

1. extract a repository for all ansible scripts and remove it from the services repositories.
2. extract a repository just for the rabbitmq ansible scripts.

Is it a good idea?

Comment: It really depends on what is it what you are doing for `RabbitMQ`. If your operations are idempotent (a-la Terraform), then it really doesn't matter to execute that as many times as services you have, but if not, it should run on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the deployment procedure for those services. Are those components are in the same administrative domain or not (are they maintained by the same team)?

If your services are part of a single installation (product) under management of a single team I suggest to go for a single repo with playbooks for each service.

If those are loosely coupled and are managed by different teams, each team may provide own deployment playbook. Common repo in this case likely cause some friction.